# RegEx for URL redirect pattern?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I need help creating redirects for a migrated site and can use RegEx. This is the before link `/cms/events/view/13-03-20/some-post_title.aspx` and this is the after `/event/some-post_title`. Anyone know of a RegEx pattern that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the last part (since you'll know that event will always be in the front of the url), then the following two will work.

This matches everything but a slash between a slash and the end of a string.

```
var newurl = '/event/' + url.match(/[^//]*$/);
```

Here's a version with replace that replaces everything up to the last slash.

```
var newurl = url.replace(/(/|^)([^/]*/)*/, '/event/');
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using `sed` can be:

```
$ echo "/cms/events/view/13-03-20/some-post_title.aspx" | sed -e 's![^/]*/[^/]\+\(/[^/]\+/\).\+/\(.\+\)\.[^\.]\+!\1\2!'
```

To interpret the RegEx, first get the two fields between the chosen separator `!`: the first dissects the input, the second replaces the matched string with a concatenation of the 1st and 2nd embraced term. That 1st term equals `/events/`, the 2nd `some-post_title`.

The rectangular brackets are used to specify a set of characters searched for: here just used to search for anything but a slash. This way the URL elements can be separated.